# Unable to save object using BackboneJS and the Indexeddb adatper

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, indexeddb

I'm creating a web app using [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/) which saves data using the [IndexedDb adapter](https://github.com/superfeedr/indexeddb-backbonejs-adapter). I am unable to persist an object as exception is thrown when calling the **save()** method, even for very simple objects.

```
var page = new Page();
page.set({
   'title': 'New page',
   'number': 1
});
page.save()
```

...which results in the error message (in Chrome).

> Exception message: Failed to execute 'add' on 'IDBObjectStore': An
>   object could not be cloned.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new object using [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/#) and the [IndexedDB adapter](https://github.com/superfeedr/indexeddb-backbonejs-adapter) you need to pass the data to the save method (rather than setting it before).

```
var page = new Page();
page.save(
    {
        'title': 'New page',
        'number': 1
    },
    {
        success: function(){
            // Object saved
        },
        error: function(){
           // An error occurred when saving
        }
    }
);
```

The project's unit tests are a really good source of examples on how to use the API: https://github.com/superfeedr/indexeddb-backbonejs-adapter/blob/master/tests/test.js